# FTP on local PC

Tags: ftp

I have setup an FTP on a PC with IP 192.168.100.200. There are some application on the same PC which will communicate via FTP to access some data from that PC itself. When i try FTP with IP address(192.168.100.200) from the same PC, couldn't succeed. i could connect to 192.168.100.200 via FTP from other PC in same network, the connection work very well.

how can i solve the above problem, so that the applications installed on the same PC and get access to data on the same PC via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to access data that's located on the same PC, why use FTP in the first place?

Is it a matter of permissions (the folder where your FTP data is stored belonging to a different user)?

If not, you might try to loopback with "ftp://127.0.0.1/your-ftp-folder", but recent versions of the major Web browser have stopped supporting FTP altogether, or are in the process of doing it (Mozilla being one of them).

Comment: That is the architecture of the system.                           The same folder can be accessed from other PC in the same network so I don't think there is any problem with the user access.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't FTP to your own IP address. If the FTP-accessible folder is on your PC, for example, you don't have to use the FTP protocol to access its content, unless it belongs to a different user on the same PC, in which case you need the user's credentials to access it. FTP was designed to grant people access to *distant* folders and directories, not local ones in the sense of, sitting in your own hard drive. Only thing you can try is send an FTP request via your Ethernet connection and receive a reply via WiFi, because then, the IP addresses will be different. But you... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 ... would have to set your FTP server to accept incoming requests from one IP, and deliver the content to another IP. EDIT: that, or use a third-party that will virtualize your FTP server, but I'm not sure that's what you want: http://www.xlightftpd.com/